# no context menu when right clicked application's title bar

Tags: release-loki

Some windows are not displaying context menu when right clicked on theirs title bar.

I'm talking about this menu:
[image]

Such applications are: Libre Office, Firefox, Chromium (using system titlebar and border), QT Creator etc...

This is not happening on gnome apps like Nautilus or Gnome-Terminal... so this might be issue only with non-gnome applications only but I can't say for sure.

This behavior is known to me since Elementary OS Luna but it is still present.

Edit:
This is not problem caused by VirtualBox, it is present on real machine too.

Comment: what are you using right now and did you make any tweaks to the UI ?

Comment: I'm using vanila Elementary OS. No modifications at all.

Comment: I was looking for something else and saw your bug so I tried and have the same issue. My profile was made from scratch, I imported settings to some apps (Chrome), but not others (LibreOffice), and can't see the menu in all of the apps you listed here.

Comment: Same problem here. Any idea ? Thanks in advance for hints !

Comment: Same problem, also !

May be a bug should be filed ?

Answer (score 1):

There was a known issue in elementary OS Loki where context menus were not displayed for non-native or "client-side decorated" apps, like Firefox or Electron apps. However, this has been fixed in elementary OS Juno.

Answer (score -2):

Try **Elementary Tweaks**. Might help.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install elementary-tweaks -y
```

[image: Elementary Tweaks]

Comment: Elementary Tweaks does not help !