# Juno: no right click menu on title bar

Tags: release-juno, context-menu, title-bar

All windows are not displaying context menu when right clicked on theirs title bar.
This used to work with a fresh install but it's not working any more on 2 recent installations.
I do not know what caused the problem and I do not intend to remove all installed programs (or to reinstall Juno) to find out.

Any pointers would be a big help.

This is related to a [Loki issue](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7655/no-context-menu-when-right-clicked-applications-title-bar) but not the same, at it is for all applications and all users.

***EDIT 29 Nov:***
I am not looking for a way to minimize the window: I can do that.

I want the *title bar menu* as it provides a menu to choose on which workspace the windows is to be displayed: one particular workspace or all workspaces.

Comment: That is not normal Elementary OS behavior. You should just accept that Elementary doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1):

elementaryOS AFAIK never had that menu, in fact in elementaryOS there's no minimize concept in the system

Probably you can see that menu in some non eOS-apps but isn't part of the environment

The link you provided is a guy who said what I said now, he wanted eOS desktop and apps to run like Gnome apps. My question is why he installed eOS and not a Gnome based system?.

He then talked about Nautilus, in eOS we have Pantheon not Nautilus. He also talked about Gnome-Terminal, again eOS don't come with Gnome, it uses GTK libaries but isn't Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

The "minimize" concept is quite standard in elementaryOS. Just click the icon in the dock, and active application will minimize to the dock.

Minimizing a single window from an application (like Pantheon File Manager) needed to be done via right clicking the title bar... But that doesn't work now, so the only remaining option is the keyboard shortcut. (I think the default is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)

Comment: Actually there's no minimize concept, in eOS it's called and it is `hide` (hence the **H** in the shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the rad tool "Lazarus" and I experienced the context menu popping up automatically(!) when I compile with gtk3 widget set. Using the default widget set there is no context menu.
Unfortunately I cannot use gtk3  constantly because some of my widgets/components are then messed up.